# What does this C++ define macro do?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

What does this define macro do? I assumed that this will print the given string to the standard output, but it just not printed out nothing. Am I wrong about this?

```
#define SCOPE_LOGGER(...)
...
void someClass::someFunction() { SCOPE_LOGGER("someClass::someFunction()"); ... }
```

Comment: From "..." nobody can tell nothing. You need to post the actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [KamilCuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75219144/5825294), that macro expands to nothing.

However, most likely it does expand to something through some other preprocessing conditional path, i.e. imho that line appears in the code like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define SCOPE_LOGGER(...) something real that does the logging
#else
#define SCOPE_LOGGER(...)
#endif
```

That's the only way that line can make sense.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I finally found the corresponding code snippet as you mentioned, just in a completely different project. Thanks for your help and time!

Answer (score 2):

> What does this define macro do?

Defines a macro function that takes any number of arguments and expands to nothing.

> Am I wrong about this?

Because the macro expands to nothing, `SCOPE_LOGGER("someClass::someFunction()")` is removed from the code. Fun fact: the trailing `;` stays.